# ffmpeg2theora parameter out of range

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, ogg

I'm trying to convert a mp4 file to ogg with ffmpeg2theora and I have a lot of "paramater out of range":

```
[NULL @ 0x633740] Value 4707126720094797824.000000 for parameter 'probesize' out of range
[NULL @ 0x633740] Value 4707126720094797824.000000 for parameter 'analyzeduration' out of range
[NULL @ 0x633740] Value 4697254411347427328.000000 for parameter 'indexmem' out of range
```

something like 50 lines of that then:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x633740] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x633740] Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), 440 kb/s)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x633740] decoding for stream 1 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x633740] Could not find codec parameters (Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s)
```

Am I missing something? codecs maybe?

TIA

greg

Comment: Why don't you just use `ffmpeg` instead?

Comment: can I use ffmpeg to create .ogg files directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I'm so stupid! I can indeed use ffmepg directly:
http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide

Thanks a lot LordNeckbeard!!